# Ramp up/down algorithm for user load testing

Tags: algorithm, load-testing

I'm working on a user load testing application for web servers and I'm trying to implement a feature for automatically ramping up the maximum number of "users" that a server can handle. I want to spawn test users until some threshold for the average response time and/or http request failure ratio is met, and then I want to kill/spawn users until a stable state just below the thresholds is found.

Essentially, I want to find the maximum stable number of concurrent users that still meets the requirements, as fast as possible.

I can of course figure out an algorithm for this myself but I'm thinking that there might be existing ramp up/ramp down algorithms that I could use. If anyone has knowledge on this I would love if you could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on what's going on and if the system begins to decay gradually or if there is a discrete drop in performance (e.g. "healthy" -> "dead").

In the second case, there's no feedback to indicate whether or not you're approaching the boundary, so you will need to first find a point that exceeds the threshold and jump between that and the largest value that doesn't exceed the threshold.  You might simplify this with 2 (or more) separate servers.  Splitting in the middle is pretty much the fastest way feasible, though if you have 10 servers, you could divide into 10 steps at each iteration.

If you get some feedback, then you're looking for a method that incorporates this.  You may find that the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) is suitable.  It's fairly easy to implement, but you'll likely find implementations in any language of interest.